# Can a domain registrar take down a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, domain-registration, dmca

I am in the middle of a DMCA request, as I have found someone who is using some of my copyrighted content. The host is based in China, and is not responding to any requests (I have sent faxes, e-mails, and a letter).

Now, as far as I was aware, it is possible for a domain registrar (the domain is registered via Network Solution) to take down a domain by changing or destroying the name server entries.

Is the assumption in the above paragraph correct?

Comment: I am specifically looking for a "Yes, that is possible by..." or "No, that is impossible because..." type answer. I know that there would be a lot of legal hoops to jump through to actually make this happen - but there's no point in recharging my lawyer-bots if there's no way to do this from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct the name server provider could take the domain offline by removing the zone information.

There however would be nothing stopping them from registering the domain again with another registrar either in the US or another country making you go through this all over again.

Comment: I think at this point it's more about getting their attention - which this action would definitely do. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would definitely get their attention.  Good luck, I've had these problems before.

Comment: A *registrar* and a *name server provider* is not the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

Their legal division may, or may not, want to get involved depending on their interpretation of safe harbor provisions -- Section 512(c)(1). I would recommend reading through them yourself, or ask your lawyers, for an opinion on the matter.